# Changing wpf image source to a jpg on runtime that is not a resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a personal movieapp that downloads pictures runtime, and I want to display the images instead of a placeholder image I put (If no picture is available)

The code I found that should do the trick changes nothing

I have this WPF image control

```
<Image Name="MovieImage" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="NoPhotoAvailable.jpg" />
```

and then I have

```
public void MovieList_SelectionChanged(Movie SelectedMovie)
    {
        this.SelectedMovie = SelectedMovie;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri("/155.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bi.EndInit();
        Console.WriteLine(bi.UriSource.ToString());

        MWV.MovieImage.Source = bi;
    }
```

Where MWV is where the image control is at

The image is placed in the apps folder and named 155.jpg but nothing is shown at all

I found alot of examples inhere that suggests that this should be pretty close to the solution but apprently not correct

Solution:

```
        public void MovieList_SelectionChanged(Movie SelectedMovie)
    {
        if (MovieCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MovieCount.ToString());
            MWV.MovieImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("NoPhotoAvailable.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else
        {
            this.SelectedMovie = SelectedMovie;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

            bi.BeginInit();
            string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(MainWindowController).Assembly.Location), this.SelectedMovie.TMDBID.ToString() + ".jpg");
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bi.EndInit();
            Console.WriteLine(bi.UriSource.ToString());

            MWV.MovieImage.Source = bi;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should store `new BitmapImage(new Uri("NoPhotoAvailable.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))` in a `static` field so that you don't keep reloading the same image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/` from your path.
A path that starts with a `/` is an *absolute* path, so your code looks for a file named `155.jpg` *in the root of the drive*.

Comment: @"c:/155.jpg" shows the image but "155.jpg" shows nothing and I need the second to work as I will make my url with this.SelectedMovie.TMDBID.ToString() + ".jpg" just typed the example there to avoid confusion

Comment: In the app folder therefore I dont understand why the "155.jpg" dont work. The C:\ was just to test if I at all could get an image shown

Comment: In the project folder or the output path?

Comment: MovieDB2\bin\Debug so in the same folder as the executeable

Comment: What's `Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: C:\Users\Skipper\Desktop\Skole\Win\Opgave 4\MovieDB2\MovieDB2\bin\Debug but maybe I can use that to create a absolute path

Comment: It would be better to use `typeof(MyClass).Assembly.Location`.

Comment: How should I type that? This works: bi.UriSource = new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "/" + this.SelectedMovie.TMDBID.ToString() + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); but cant seem to just replace it with your code (and exchange myclass with the class that its inside)

Comment: You need to use `Path.GetDirectoryName`  (`Assembly.Location` is the path to the file).  In your code, you don't need `.ToString()`, and you should call `Path.Combine`.

Comment: It will still work if the first part already ends with a `\​`.

Comment: Posted my solution in the question now, hope thats what your mean

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what I meant.